# using d-flex to center content. trying to align the content in divs to all be the same using d-flex (bootstrap4)

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-4, jsx

I'm following the flex order from the documentation.

I have the title for the first flex item and wanted may paragraph to have the same alignment as my title as well as my button. Would I need to use CSS for it or can it be done with bootstrap alone?

```
 <div className="d-flex align-items-center flex-column bd-highlight mb-3">
  <div className="mb-auto p-2 bd-highlight">Title</div>
  <div className="p-2 bd-highlight">paragraph</div>
  <div className="p-2 bd-highlight"> buttons</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Building in react

Comment: Can you show how this looks as of now with your code? pretty sure it can be done only with bootstrap classes, but I'm not entirely clear on the issue

Comment: What is the question? Is it working with the code you've posted?